# Can you use metamagic feat on a spell where it will have no effect?

Tags: metamagic

If you have the "extend spell" metamagic feat, can you use it on the level 1 "Burning hands", just to cast it as a level 2 spell?

Comment: Sounds like this is D&D, but which edition are you asking about?

Comment: I'm making a guess here: Maybe he wonders if you can use a metamagic feat ONLY to raise the spell-level, without having the extra effect affect the spell. Still, he should clarify this himself first.

Comment: @CharlieHorse Speaking of pet peeves, [comments aren't for chatting or venting](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). Review those guidelines, and please use them for constructive purposes. (We have [chat] for chatting. :)